# HTML/CSS - Extra menu spacing when viewed from mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, menu, border

I have an unordered list-based menu system on my site. On desktop, it's exactly as I want it. No borders or spacing: [image]

Then, one mobile (I am testing with iPad/iPhone), it looks like this:[image]

With a gray border around the entire thing and between certain buttons.

The HTML that renders the page is this:

```
 <ul class="menu">
     <li class="<? echo( ($page == "main" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=main">Home</a></li>
     <li class="<? echo( ($page == "products" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a></li>
     <li class="<? echo( ($page == "partners" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=partners">Partners</a></li>
     <li class="menu_li"><a href="http://forums.tfdidesign.com">Forums</a></li>
 </ul>
```

And the css is as follows:

```
.menu {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0;
    list-style: none;        
    font-size: 15px;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #fafafa;    
    margin-top:5px;
    width:930px;
    float:left;        
}

    .menu a {
        color: #fafafa;    
        text-decoration:none;
    }

    .menu_li:first-child {
        float:left;
        border-top-left-radius:5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    }

    .menu_li:last-child {
        float:left;
        border-top-right-radius:5px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    }

.menu_li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 232px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #282828;    
}

    .menu_li:hover {
        background-color: #404040;
    }

    .menu_li:active {
        background-color: #545454;
    }

    .menu_li a {        
        display: block;        
        color: inherit;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    /* active */

    .menu_li_current {
    float: left;
    line-height: 33px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 232px;
    height: 36px;
    background-color: #696969;
}

.menu_li_current a {    
    display: block;    
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

    .menu_li_current:first-child {
        border-top-left-radius: 5px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    }
```

Any advice on getting rid of the border on mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Change your Html to this:

```
<ul class="menu">
 <li class="<? echo( ($page == "main" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=main">Home</a></li>
 <li class="<? echo( ($page == "products" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=products">Products</a></li>
 <li class="<? echo( ($page == "partners" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="index.php?p=partners">Partners</a></li>
 <li class="<? echo( ($page == "forums" ? "menu_li_current" : "menu_li") );?>"><a href="http://forums.tfdidesign.com">Forums</a></li>
</ul>
```

I dont think that sth is wrong with the css. Because every button has the same setting.
The last lines of your Html-Code is a bit different to the other. This would be the problem. Hope it helped

Comment: It actually ended up needing a "margin-right:-1px" and some adjustment to the size.